# How import the stylesheet into a namespaced class with postcss?

Tags: css, postcss, flatpickr

I have some [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) styles which I'd like to isolate from other calendar instances. In my postcss file I'd like to import the flatpickr styles within a namespaces class to achieve this isolation so that these default stlyes do not bleed into other flatpickr instances on my site.

```
.Houses__grid-calendar-fields {
  @import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css';
}
```

I was hoping that the above would work, but I get “Unknown Property Name” in chrome. If I were to lift the import outside of the namespace to the top of the postcss file, then indeed the styles get imported, but they unfortunately spread across the site which impacts my other flatpickr calendar instances which are using completely custom styling.

Has anyone been able to import a stylesheet into a namespaced class with postcss?